# How to accelerate a charge without emitting radiation?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, acceleration, charge

When a charge accelerates it emittes radiation.  So is there any way to accelerate charge and not emit radiation?

Comment: [Electromagnetic field of an accelerated charge](http://www.tapir.caltech.edu/~teviet/Waves/empulse.html)

Comment: Let it fall in a gravititational field

Comment: Whether an accelerating charge necessarily radiates is still an open question in the classical theory. While we know that a rotating charge does radiate, according to Feinman, a uniformly accelerating charge does not: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox_of_a_charge_in_a_gravitational_field#Proposal_of_Feynman See also: http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath528/kmath528.htm

Comment: @JohnRennie would you care to elaborate? Safesphere's comment about Feynman's hypothesis might be what you are hinting at but that contradicts Anna V's answer. I would be interested in your reasoning.

Answer (score 3):

> When a charge accelerates it emittes radiation.

This is an experimental observation, a fact of nature, which has been fitted within an elaborate, predictive and very accurate theory of electrodynamics. This theory is continuously validated .

> So is there any way to accelerate charge and not emit radiation?

This would invalidate Maxwwell's theory , so the answer is no, not for single charges. Complex charges adding up to 0 charge of course can be accelerated as part of the ensemble without radiating as long as there are no charge field assymetries. A falling ball for example,  does not radiate although it is  made up of  a large number of charges which add up to 0 total charge.

Comment: whether or not the total charge is zero, the spatial distribution of charges in such an ensemble and differential acceleration of opposite charges will give rise to [higher-order moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_radiation) and nontrivial radiation patterns even in cases of ordinary neutral objects (although the magnitude may be circumstantially insignificant). consider a typical dipole antenna is virtually always electrically neutral